# C# Xml - Invalid name character; The ' ' character cannot be included in a name

Tags: c#, xml, database

So Im making a music player in C#. When a user opens a song, i want it to be saved to a xml file (it saves its path, its name and its duration). Whenever I try to send the value to the library that does the saving I get this error.

```
MusicLibraryWriter.DatabaseWriter+MyException: System.ArgumentException: Invalid name character in 'Song file path'. The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name.
```

Here is my code:

```
    public string addToDatabasedataBaseInfo( songInfo dataToWrite)
    {
        try
        {

            string newSongPath = dataToWrite.songFilePath;
            XmlWriter databaseWriter = XmlWriter.Create("databaseEdit.xml");
            databaseWriter.WriteStartDocument();
            databaseWriter.WriteStartElement("Songs");
            databaseWriter.WriteElementString("Song file path", newSongPath);
            databaseWriter.WriteElementString("Song duration", dataToWrite.songDuration.ToString());
            databaseWriter.WriteEndElement();
            databaseWriter.WriteEndDocument();
            databaseWriter.Close();
            //databaseWriter.Dispose ();

            mergeDataBase();


            return "Success";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new MyException(e.ToString());

        }
    }
```

Comment: dataToWrite.songFilePath contains an empty string when it's used?

Comment: @MarvinSmit: That would be fine - it's the element *name* which is the problem.

Comment: Doh. So obvious i missed it. :) Spaces not allowed in XML element names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
databaseWriter.WriteElementString("Song file path", newSongPath);
```

You're trying to create an element with a name of `Song file path`, and that's not valid in XML. Element names can't contain spaces. You could use something like:

```
databaseWriter.WriteElementString("SongFilePath", newSongPath);
```

(You'll need to do the same thing for the duration, of course.)

Note that although in this case your code is reasonably simple, for more complicated XML you'd probably be better off building up an `XDocument` and then saving that to disk. Also, you should use a `using` statement for your writer, so it's disposed automatically even if there's an exception. (You can then remove the `Close` call.)

Also note that despite your method name implying that it will *add* an entry, it's actually going to replace the file completely with just the single song in it.

Finally, you should follow .NET naming conventions, naming your methods and types in PascalCase (leading capital letter).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked ! As for the XDocument, the code is still simple, but I will look for optimization after I manage to make a stable build.

Comment: @user220258: It's not optimization - it's simplification of the code. `XmlWriter` can be slightly painful to use... in particular, when you try adding an element, it's going to be much harder to do that with `XmlWriter` than reading the whole file into an `XDocument`, adding an element, then saving the whole document again...

Comment: For now ill use `XmlWriter`, but ill look into `XDocument`, because the Xml Database is going to be important.